# Set to executable installed by Visual Studio 2017 admin rights

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, windows-installer

I am using
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=visualstudioclient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects
extension for creating installer package (C# forms).

I would like to set permanently admin rights to .exe unpackaged by the installer (as many applications have e.g. Matlab, Visual Studio). How to do it?

The main reason is, that I need to add/remove files into C:\ location where the .exe is located (Admin rights required).

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong program file structure problem. These temporary files should be placed c:\ProgramData or C:\Users"USER_NAME"\AppData